# Divide list of columns by a second list of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have script that generates a `data.table` with some columns I want to divide by some other columns and store the results in new columns. Here's an example.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(V1 = c( 5.553465,  4.989168,  2.563682,  6.987971, 19.220936),
                 V2 = c(4.248335, 19.768138,  3.840026, 17.411003, 17.939368),
                 V3 = c(9.683953, 15.344424, 11.729091,  7.534210,  5.404000),
                 V4 = c(5.949093,  4.553023,  9.765656, 11.211069,  4.085964),
                 V5 = c(11.814671,  5.460138,  2.492230,  1.48792,  8.164280))

list1 <- list(c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
list2 <- list(c("V2", "V4", "V5"))
listRatio <- list(c("rat1","rat2","rat3"))
```

I have tried a variety of approaches to dividing the values in the list1 elements by the values in the list2 elements, unsuccessfully. Two are below; neither works.

```
dt[, (listRatio) := list1/list2]
dt[, c("rat1","rat2","rat3") := mapply(dt, function(x,y) x / y, x = c(V1, V2, V3),  y = c(V2, V4, V5))]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to convert the `list` to `vector` by using `[[` and then get the values of each vector in a `list` with `mget`, use `Map` to divide (`/`) the corresponding columns of each of the `list` values and assign it to the vector (`listRatio[[1]]`).

```
dt[, (listRatio[[1]]) := Map(`/`, mget(list1[[1]]), mget(list2[[1]]))]
dt
#          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5      rat1      rat2      rat3
#1:  5.553465  4.248335  9.683953  5.949093 11.814671 1.3072098 0.7141147 0.8196549
#2:  4.989168 19.768138 15.344424  4.553023  5.460138 0.2523843 4.3417611 2.8102630
#3:  2.563682  3.840026 11.729091  9.765656  2.492230 0.6676210 0.3932174 4.7062635
#4:  6.987971 17.411003  7.534210 11.211069  1.487920 0.4013537 1.5530190 5.0635854
#5: 19.220936 17.939368  5.404000  4.085964  8.164280 1.0714389 4.3904861 0.6619077
```

NOTE: As @Frank mentioned in the comments, it is better to create a `vector` of variables names and not a `list`.

Comment: I know enough about R now to benefit from a bit of tutorial on when to use lists of character variables and when to use vectors, with a data table focus if that's relevant. Can anyone add a link to such a tutorial?

Comment: An improvement to the answer (at least for my purposes) is to use `as.vector` for the lists and use `dt[, (listRatio) := Map(`/`, mget(list1), mget(list2))]`. This automatically generates values of all the elements of listRatio.

Answer (score 2):

By using data.frame function

```
dt <- data.frame(V1 = c( 5.553465,  4.989168,  2.563682,  6.987971, 19.220936),
                 V2 = c(4.248335, 19.768138,  3.840026, 17.411003, 17.939368),
                 V3 = c(9.683953, 15.344424, 11.729091,  7.534210,  5.404000),
                 V4 = c(5.949093,  4.553023,  9.765656, 11.211069,  4.085964),
                 V5 = c(11.814671,  5.460138,  2.492230,  1.48792,  8.164280))

list1 <- list(dt[,c("V1", "V2", "V3")])
list2 <- list(dt[,c("V2", "V4", "V5")])
dt$rat3 <- dt$rat2 <- dt$rat1 <- ""
dt[, c("rat1","rat2","rat3")] <- unlist(list1)/unlist(list2)

         V1        V2        V3        V4        V5      rat1      rat2      rat3
1  5.553465  4.248335  9.683953  5.949093 11.814671 1.3072098 0.7141147 0.8196549
2  4.989168 19.768138 15.344424  4.553023  5.460138 0.2523843 4.3417611 2.8102630
3  2.563682  3.840026 11.729091  9.765656  2.492230 0.6676210 0.3932174 4.7062635
4  6.987971 17.411003  7.534210 11.211069  1.487920 0.4013537 1.5530190 5.0635854
5 19.220936 17.939368  5.404000  4.085964  8.164280 1.0714389 4.3904861 0.6619077
```

Comment: The question was about data.table solutions.  In addition, you have changed the OP's `list1`, `list2` etc according to what you consider as appropriate.

Comment: @akrun ya you are right, just giving an idea if he uses data.frame function instead of data.table

Comment: In that case, it is okay.

Comment: I'm coding exclusively in data table now, both for its speed and because having both is potentially confusing when I produce one type for output as a .rds file in one script and potentially read it into several others.